# Using Array inside and outside AWK statement

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk

I'd like to store inputs from user in array inside AWK statment then display the elements of that array outside AWK statement.
The Problem is that I can't  display the array elements outside the AWK
And here is the code :

```
declare -a data
awk -F" " ' 
BEGIN{
cmd="read a; echo $a"
}
{
        i=1;
        NR==1;
        while(i<=NF)
        {
        print $i
        printf "Please Enter " $i ":  "
        cmd|getline input
        close(cmd)
        **data[$i]=input**
        print data[$i] 
        print  $i,NF 
        i++
        }
}
' basic_data

#Here I want to display array elements but i get nothing:

echo  ${data[@]}
```

Appreciate your kind support
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Bash and awk are different processes. It's impossible for them to access and modify each other's data.

Comment: What is in `basic_data` ?

Comment: It looks like you are very confused about what shell and awk are for as you're trying to use awk for things that shell should be used for, and then trying to populate shell data structures inside an awk script. It'd be better if you told us what you're trying to do , with sample input/output so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Dears, 
What I'm trying to do is to let the user insert data according to fields stored in "basic_data" file

Ex, Data stored in basic data file is Id and Name

so t'm using AWK with condition "NR=1" to get the fields and then let the user insert data according to them and store them in an array so that i can do some validations on them.

Hope now that we are in the same page :) .... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a variable's value into `awk`, you can assign it to an awk variable with the `-v` switch. To receive data back from `awk` into a variable, you can use command substitution.

```
$ a=aaa
$ b=($(awk -va="$a" 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {printf("%s%d\n", a, i)}}'))
$ for x in "${b[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done
aaa1
aaa2
aaa3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
array=($(awk 'BEGIN{print "first";print "second"}')) 

echo ${array[0]}
first
echo ${array[1]}
second
```

but I am not sure if that is what you mean.